# SQL - Delete object with inner join

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to delete an object from my store using SQL and an inner join

Here is what I have:

```
DELETE appointment_object
FROM appointment_table appointment_object
INNER JOIN sales_person_table sales_person_object
ON appointment_object.made_by.personno = sales_person_object.personno
WHERE sales_person_object.personno = 3;
```

Here's my error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

all property names and table names are correct, though.

I'm also getting some syntax highlighting between `appointment_object
FROM` with the error:

```
Expected WHERE, PARTITION
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've also tried getting the object using a SELECT query and it returns with the object I want to delete

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Not a duplicate, I've tried those solutions and none of them work

Comment: You're right I did, just changed that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rephrasing this using `exists` or `in`:

```
DELETE
    FROM appointment_table
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM sales_person_table sp
                  WHERE a.made_by.personno = sp.personno AND
                        sp.personno = 3
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sadly I get this error `Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:`

Comment: That is an Oracle error. You tagged your post with sql server so of course the responses are for sql server. However, the above query should work in any DBMS.

Comment: I've updated my tag, apologies. The query doesn't work though, outputs the above error.

Comment: Removing the `a`  so it just reads `DELETE FROM` does work, thanks